# Listen to ENTER key in Android

Tags: android, keylistener, enter

Here is my code:

```
public class CaptureENTER extends Activity implements OnKeyListener{

/* on create and other stuff in here*/

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
           Toast.makeText(LiVoiceActivity.this,
                                     "YOU CLICKED ENTER KEY",
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }       
        return false;
    }
```

I don't know what is going on, but when I press the ENTER key in my keyboard (I am using the Android emulator), **the event is not activated**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19):

Returning `true` is not the issue.

You're failing because you must set the listener to a `View`, not just the `Activity`.

**edited for clarification:**

The return value of the listener is not meant to be understood as a signal that the event will or will not be called. And it couldn't anyway, since the `return` clause is only called *after* your `Toast` is shown.

It's a signal to the system that further action is needed (return `false`) or that the method handled the event fully and properly (return `true`). That's why the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) says in these words:

> **Returns**
>
> True if the listener has ***consumed*** the event, false otherwise.

---

There's a difference between:

- Implementing the `View.OnKeyListener` `interface` in your `Activity` class.

That allows your `Activity` to implement the functionality provided by the interface in your class, i.e., to *declare* to the world that your `Activity` knows how to handle that kind of event.

Please pay attention to the fact that I said "*declare*". Just because you declared that you know how to handle a task doesn't mean people will give that task to you, *nor does it mean that you can generate such tasks by yourself*. It's a good metaphor for the `implements` keyword in my opinion. Here the `Activity` "asks for a task".

**Metaphors aside, technically, the `Activity` is defining a way to handle that event, but it can't generate that kind of event by itself.**

- setting the `View` callbacks to your `Activity` implementation

Using that, a `View` binds to a listener (which happens to be your `Activity`), promising to notify it whenever the event happens.

It "contracts" with your `Activity` to receive an input (the user presses the ENTER key while the `View` is in focus) and notifies the `Activity`. And since the `Activity` previously declared that it's capable of performing that, ***BOTH* parties can execute the contract as previously agreed** (see previous item).

**Metaphors aside again, technically, here the `Activity` is registered by the `View` to be notified later when the `View` trigger the event. The `Activity` declares *how*, but the `View` knows *when*.**

**Conclusion:**

This is just a metaphor for `interface`s (at least in this case). It may look complicated, but it's crystal clear when you think of it as a two-party agreement. If you need a better, technical, explanation, I suggest reading about `interface`s.

---

**Answer to the new comment question:**

> Hello David and everyone else. Really I can't set a listener to the whole Activity?

Not in that way. You need to override `dispatchKeyEvent`. An example:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
    Toast.makeText(UITestsActivity.this,
               "YOU CLICKED ENTER KEY",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

Comment: Ah, and of course it must be the one focused... otherwise how would we differentiate between Views anyway in non-touch mode... I'm sure you're paying attention to that, right? right? ;-)

Comment: Hello David and everyone else. Really I can't set a listener to the whole Activity?

Comment: I updated my answer with the answer to this new question. In short: you can, but not in the way you're trying.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
public class CaptureENTER extends Activity implements OnKeyListener{ 

/* on create and other stuff in here*/ 

    @Override 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { 
           Toast.makeText(LiVoiceActivity.this, 
                                     "YOU CLICKED ENTER KEY", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          return true;

        }        
        return false; 
    }
```

**EDIT:**
[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489607/david-cesarino) is CORRECT!!

Returning true is not the issue.

You're failing because you must set the listener to a View, not just the Activity.