# Start Activity when a key is hit

Tags: android, keylistener

I want to start an activity when the user presses the space bar.  My code is not detecting when the space bar is clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CLICKED SPACE KEY",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Didnt work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either set the listener to a `View` **that has *current* focus**, or use `dispatchKeyEvent` in your `Activity`, as seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237860/489607).

Both will work.

---

**Answer for your comments:** If you've followed my link, you've probably implemented [`Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) by now. :-)

> The code doesnt register anykey i press, but when i push the back key
>   it toasts for me "didnt work"

**Do you happen to be using the emulator?** I ask that because the latest SDK seems to have some problems with the emulator keyboard. The special keys (DPAD, HOME, BACK etc.) work, but the onscreen, QWERTY keyboard does not register any presses. The physical keyboard in my laptop won't register any presses either.

Don't ask me why.

And I say that because this week I posted the answer in the link, and it was working fine. The change is that I updated the Android SDK to R20/JB this morning, so I guess it could be a factor.

However, it will **just work** on a ***real* device**. I've just connected a physical keyboard to my tablet (P7510 / Honeycomb 3.2), and **it listens to space presses just fine.**

In case you're still doubting, here is proof: :-)

[image]

Comment: So yes, either you didn't set that listener to a View, or the View for which you set the listener is not under focus when you press space bar.

Comment: I re edited my code using dispatchkeyevent.  I'm going to try it the other way but meanwhile my updated code is posted.

Comment: So, did it work? Does the Toast appear not when you press the ENTER key?

Comment: The code doesnt register anykey i press, but when i push the back key it toasts for me "didnt work"

Comment: I updated the answer to address your concerns. PLEASE take a look.

Comment: I'm still on this problem.  I've tried it on my HTC Inspire and im still not getting a response from space key.

Comment: lol, someone thought I had wrote "yo" (as in street language)... it was a typo ("*to*" your answer). But anyway, thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

This function can be used to check that which key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, what I have done is , I have used the overridden function 'onKey'

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == nNeededKeyCode)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

p.s. firstly you need to make use of 'OnKeyListener()' to get the key press event

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the copy/paste answer, but this should accomplish what you're attempting.

This will take place when the user presses the "spacebar" and then lets the spacebar go. If you don't want to wait for them to let it go, you can remove my boolean values, and execute your code in the onKeyDown function. Hope this helps.

```
boolean spacePressed = false;
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       switch (keyCode) {
               case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
               {
                  spacePressed = true;
                  return true;
                }
               // other cases can go here
    }

    return true;
}// End of onKeyDown



@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
   if (spacePressed){
       // start intent

       // make this false again, so other keys won't trigger it
       spacePressed = false;
   }

    return true;
}// End of onKeyUp
```